# JsonView class with Swagger @ApiResponse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a `@JsonView` named `BankAccountView.Public` who help me to restrict some fields in `BankAccount` because I don't want to send all their attributes in a public get operation. My issue is when I try to specify it using swagger because if I specify `BankAccount.class` it shows the entire object instead of all the fields specify in my `@JsonView`, but if I specify `BankAccount.Public.class` it show me an empty object. Could you please tell me if it is possible that Swagger shows only the public fields?

Here is my code:

```
// BankAccount Json View
public class BankAccountView {
    public static class Public {}
}
```

```
// BankAccount class
@ApiModel("BankAccount")
public class BankAccount {

    @ApiModelProperty
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private Long accountId;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private Long owner;

    @ApiModelProperty
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private String currency;

    @ApiModelProperty
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private String bankName;

    @ApiModelProperty
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private BankAccountType accountType;

    @ApiModelProperty
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private BankAccountStatus status;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private Instant verificationDate;

    @ApiModelProperty
    @JsonView(BankAccountView.Public.class)
    private String mask;
}
```

```
// BankAccountController class

    @ApiOperation(value = "Fetch a list of all bank accounts")
    @JsonView({BankAccountView.Public.class})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Bank accounts successfully retrieved", response = BankAccountView.Public.class, responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Validation failed", response = ApiHttpClientErrorException.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "User is not an employee", response = ResourceForbiddenException.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found", response = NoSuchElementException.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = ApiHttpServerErrorException.class)
    })
    @GetMapping
    public List<BankAccount> getAllBankAccounts() {
        return service.getAll();
    }
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What version of Springfox Swagger are you using?

Comment: I use springfox-swagger2 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
If you're using Jackson, you can use @JsonIgnore.
```

else set hidden true for individual properties

```
@ApiModelProperty(position = 1, required = true, hidden=true, notes = "used to display user name")
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in this solution but I think the problem is when I try to get 2 or more versions of the same object. For example, in my case I have a couple of attributes only for internal use but I would like to keep open handle with more than one version of this object. Thanks for your answer @sankar :)